# Can we enable iPhone Speaker On before Calling using NSUrl("tel:") scheme

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios

Can we enable iPhone speaker on before calling using NSUrl("tel:") scheme in objective c and Xamarin.iOS? If so then how we can achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Apple exposes any public API to do this.  The user must choose the audio out channel.

Answer (score 0):

To enable speaker while calling for open in Objective C, you can do something like this :

```
- (void)setAudioOutputSpeaker:(BOOL)enabled
{
    AVAudioSession *session =   [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *error;
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
    [session setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:&error];
    if (enabled) // Enable speaker
    {
        [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];
    }
    else // Disable speaker
    {
        [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error];
    }
    [session setActive:YES error:&error];
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work. I think that will be for VoIP Call not for SIM Call that we do using "tel" url scheme. I think Jason is right that Apple does expose such api to do this.